# NumPy/Pandas: remove sequential duplicate values (equivalent of bash uniq without sort)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a Pandas Series (or numpy array) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
myseries = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1])
```

Is there a good way to remove sequential duplicates, much like the unix `uniq` tool does?  The numpy/pandas `unique()` and pandas `drop_duplicates` functions remove all duplicates (like unix's `| sort | uniq`), but I don't want this:

```
>>> print(myseries.unique())
[1 2 3 4]
```

I want this:

```
>>> print(myseries.my_mystery_function())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed `Series` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
myseries = myseries[myseries.ne(myseries.shift())].tolist()
print (myseries)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

If performance is important, use `Divakar` solution.

Comment: Also may have trouble if `np.nan` is present.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `slicing` -

```
In [62]: a = myseries.values

In [63]: a[np.r_[True,a[:-1]!= a[1:]]]
Out[63]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Might have trouble if `np.nan` is present.

Answer (score 0):

A version of jezrael's using `!=`:

```
print(myseries[myseries!=myseries.shift()].tolist())
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: An operator is not a good enough excuse to copy 99% of another answer.

Comment: @coldspeed Oh Okay, let me delete this, okay...

Comment: It's up to you! I commented in good faith.

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you so much, i think i should keep...